# Авторизация пользователя в Spring Security через Postman

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, spring-security, postman

не получается авторизироваться через Postman

В WEB все работает, через браузер. а вот в API не хочет. Возможно что-то не дописал.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

База данных Postgress

```
@SpringBootApplication 
public class WebSecurity11Application extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login-form").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/personal-area")
            .hasAnyRole(USER.name(), ADMIN.name())
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .usernameParameter("email")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .loginPage("/login-form")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/personal-area")
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login-form");
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(WebSecurity11Application.class, args);
 }
}
```

.

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor 
public class CustomGrantedAuthority implements GrantedAuthority {

private final static String PREFIX = "ROLE_";
private final UserRole userRole;

@Override
public String getAuthority() {
    return PREFIX + userRole.name();
 }
}
```

.

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CustomUserDetails implements UserDetails {
private final Long id;
private final String email;
private final String pass;
private final Collection<CustomGrantedAuthority> getAuthorities;


@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    return getAuthorities;
}

@Override
public String getPassword() {
    return pass;
}

@Override
public String getUsername() {
    return email;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return true;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
 }
}
```

.

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
private final ServiceUserRepository serviceUserRepository;

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    ServiceUser user = serviceUserRepository.findByEmail(email);
    if (user == null) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Не найден юзер по email " + email);
    }
    return new CustomUserDetails(user.getId(), user.getEmail(), user.getPass(), user.getRoles()
            .stream()
            .map(CustomGrantedAuthority::new)
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
  }
}
```

.

```
public enum UserRole {
USER,
ADMIN
}
```

.

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class ServiceUser {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "email")
private String email;

@Column(name = "pass")
private String pass;

@ElementCollection(targetClass = UserRole.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@CollectionTable(name = "user_role")
@Column(name = "role")
private Set<UserRole> roles = emptySet();
}
```

.

```
@Repository
public interface ServiceUserRepository extends JpaRepository<ServiceUser, Long> {
ServiceUser findByEmail(String email);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello</title>
    <link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <form action="/login" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail">Email address</label>
                    <input name="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail" placeholder="Enter email" type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputPassword" class="form-label">Password</label>
                    <input name="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword" placeholder="Enter password" type="password">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Войти</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Вы открываете форму входа, и логично, что видите ее. Попробуйте ввести логин и пароль в тело запроса как поля email и password и отправить ее. Тогда по логике настроек вам должна открыться страница `/personal-area`

Comment: т.е. в Postman вместо  authorization кликаю на Body raw  пишу тело {
    "email": "1@mail.ru",
    "password":"password" кликаю на send  и мимо.
}

Comment: нет! форма! не raw, а form-data

Comment: забил в key email- в value 1@mail.ru; pasword-pasword.

Comment: Спасибо! все заработало

Answer (score 0):

заполнять нужно было в form-data, а не в authorization !